# Finding amount of palindrome integers between boundaries - Java Debugging

Tags: java, integer, range, palindrome

The code below has stylistic flaws plus a bug or two. List as many flaws as you can.

```
public int palindromeCount (int start, int finish) {
   int k = start;
   int returnVal = 0;
    while (k<finish) {
      int temp = k;
      int r = 0;
      while (temp > 0) {
         r = 10 * r + temp%10;
         temp = temp/10;
      }
      if (r == k) {
         returnVal++;
      }
      k++;
   }
   return returnVal;
}
```

Palindrome is basically a number that has the same value if reversed, such as 11. The code here needs to browse through a range and finally end up with the amount of palindromes within that range. I'm doing this to learn loops.

Here is my progress:

```
public class Counter{

   public Counter(){
  }

   public int palindromeCount (int start, int finish) {
      int returnVal = 0;
      int temp = start;

      while (start < finish) {
         int reverse = 0;

         while (temp != 0) {
           reverse = 10 * reverse + temp % 10;
            temp = temp/10;
         }

         if (temp == start) {
            returnVal = returnVal + 1;
         }
         start = start + 1;
      }
      return returnVal;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us the bugs you have found? or you want us to debug it

Comment: I have tried to debug it myself, but I just can't find what's wrong with the code. I need some guidance here with debugging. I'm currently trying to learn loops.

Comment: But how do you know that there is something wrong with your code? In wich cases it fails?

Comment: It fails for every case when there are palindromes between the specified range. It will always return 0.

Comment: Remove the return statement because in first iteration it return the control at the calling postion. so you got the 0 as your answer.

Comment: That is not the error, if he removes return he will get an error.

Comment: @christian ya there is my mistake in method header there is some changes in the return type because if it return the control at the calling position then he will get the 0 as the output from my view method return type is void and if the number is palindrome then print on the console of store in the array type of the variable then return it. if you want to receive the value of the Palindrom number.

Comment: You're right, a solution could be **(1): make method void and store results in a class field**. **(2): make method return an array**, so he can access the palindromes. But as far as he only wants the number of palindromes **(3): returning an int** will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you posted this before, as far as I've tested it, it works well.

```
public static int palindromeCount(int start, int finish) {
    int k = start;
    int returnVal = 0;
    while (k <= finish) { // Changed to <= to consider "finish" too
        int temp = k;
        int r = 0;
        while (temp > 0) {
            r = 10 * r + temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if (r == k) {
            returnVal++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```